# Make JSON request from Android app to PHP

Tags: php, android

I am new to PHP. How can I call this PHP script from an Android app?

```
<?php
$json_data=$_POST['tagtrack_scans'];
$data=json_decode($json_data, true);

echo $data['email'];
echo $data['scanned_as'];
echo $data['product_id'];

$dbhost = 'localhost:2082';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db( 'tagtrack_scans' );
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected to tagtrack_scans';

$sql="INSERT INTO tagtrack_scans (email, scanned_as, product_id)
VALUES ($email, $canned_As, $product_id)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: **(1)** You just exposed your DB username/password, so change those immediately. **(2)** It doesn't matter if you do not know PHP, call the URL via Android code and act upon the response received.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HttpClient httpclient;
    int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    int WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    JSONObject postjson;
    URL url = null;
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        try {

            postjson = new JSONObject();
            postjson.put(your_data_here);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if (response != null)
            {
               // do something with it
            }
         } catch {.....
```